# GPS-трекер на Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Нужно сделать программку (фоновую), которая будет получать текущее местоположение и отправлять на сервер (через некоторое время).
Ну и может есть еще возможность получить скорость. 
Может кто поможет примером кода или даже проектиком поделится.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. Когда-то взял за основу проект - [gpslogger](https://code.google.com/p/gpslogger/)

> GPSLogger is a simple Android service that records your GPS location to a SQLite database, and provides a KML export function so the track can be viewed in Google Earth. Though there are currently a number of Android applications available that track your location, most of them focus on Maps API interaction and sending your location to a subscription site for display on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо определиться с тем, что Вы хотите сделать. Работать только с ЖПС, что существенно ограничивает возможности в связи с его недоступностью в закрытых помещениях да и даже при плохой погоде. Или же использовать параллельно навигацию по вайфаю, сотовому оператору. Почитайте Голощапова. К сожалению непомню какая именно его книга, но касается системных возможностей андроида. В сети есть в свободном доступе. Там прям глава посвященная выбору актуального на данный момент провайдера координат с примером. 
А если только жпс, то там собственно и делать почти самому ничего не надо, кроме как координаты куда-то складывать :)