# GPS. Точка А и точка Б. Расстояние между ними в метрах

Tags: java, android, java-ee, android-sdk, activity

Хочу написать программу, которая бы считывала координаты А и координаты Б, а после - расстояние в метрах между ними.

Google ерунду всякую дает, какие-то онлайн калькуляторы или же расстояние между точками А и Б на плоскости, что-то из геометрии.

В общем, поискал на сайте, нашел 2 темы, но пользы ноль от них, хотя вторая по названию то что надо было, но ответа никакого там нет:

[hashcode.ru/questions/319220/gps-трекер-на-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/319220/gps-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android)
[hashcode.ru/questions/351309/измерение-расстояния-пройденного-за-день-gps-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/351309/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-gps-android)

Я вижу точку А, вижу точку Б, но LES=0, почти всегда, я хожу по дому, 8 шагов влево измеряю 8 шагов в право, числа тысячные меняются в А и Б, но все равно LES=0.

Что я не так делаю? Подскажите.

Comment:     или же расстояние между точками А и Б на плоскости, что - то из геометрии.

неплохой вариант

Comment: дам более точную ссылку https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java#L172

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вычисление расстояния и начального азимута между двумя точками на сфере](http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Лично я предпочитаю формулу гаверосинусов.